# Firebase Crashes iMessage Extension

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crash

Inside of my MessagesViewController (first view controller to load) I have the code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
    }
```

It works to load firebase into my iMessage extension initially, but then it crashed the extension when it tries to run again once the app exits and you are viewing the transcript.  I used breakpoints to pinpoint the error, and it is `FirebaseApp.configure()` running for the second time. Does anyone know how to prevent this crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work through:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if(FirebaseApp.app() == nil){
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            ref = Database.database().reference()
        }
    }
```